# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available" only from ant, works fine in eclipse

Tags: ant, testng, easymock, powermock

I'm using EasyMock3.1/testNg-5.7/Powermock-easymock-1.5-full.
The code is very simple, just mock a public static method.

```
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.createMock;

import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.mockStatic;

import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.replay;

import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.verify;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;


@PrepareForTest( {MyStatic.class})

public class StaticTest extends PowerMockTestCase{

  @Test

  public void testStaticMethod()

  {

   mockStatic( MyStatic.class );

    expect( MyStatic.getString() ).andReturn( "good" );

    replay( MyStatic.class );

    MyStatic.getString();

    verify(MyStatic.class);

  }

}
```

I'm using testng-eclipse plugin, It works fine within eclipse.
But when i try to run it via ant, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:520)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:498)
```

It complains at code "expect( MyStatic.getString() ).andReturn( "good" );"

My ant script is:

```
 <testng classpathref="test.runtime.classpath" outputDir="${report.absolute.path}/testngreport" workingDir="${test.module.basedir}">


          <!--<jvmarg line="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=y"/>-->


          <classfileset dir="${test.module.testoutput.dir}" includes="**/*.class"/>

        </testng>
```

I appreciate any feedback, thanks!

Comment: did you get this one sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, try running with the @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) annotation when running in ant (via junit). The @RunWith annotation looks like the only difference between your static method test example and [the one from the powermock documentation](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/source/browse/trunk/modules/module-test/easymock/junit4-test/src/test/java/samples/junit4/singleton/MockStaticTest.java).

This might have been a testng bug. I tried reproducing your failure in ant but everything worked fine for me. Here are the jar files I used:

```
$ ls -1 lib/
cglib-nodep-2.2.3.jar
easymock-3.1.jar
javassist.jar
objenesis-1.4.jar
powermock-easymock-1.5.1-full.jar
testng-6.8.jar
```

Comment: @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) can be used with junit test only.

Comment: Right, I'll update my answer to mention try running via JUnit in ant for comparison.

Comment: Updated my answer to mention this scenario worked in ant (for me) with the listed jar versions.